# R plot color legend by factor

Tags: r, plot, colors, legend, r-factor

Using R 3.3.1 in Windows 10.  I'm making an x-y plot from 95 rows of data.  The data are in 6 different groupings (a factor called "group").  **The plot itself is easy enough, but I can't get the legend to properly account for the factor and color correctly.**

Here's the data in a variable v1:

```
v1 <- structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("F9", "T26", "W37", 
"W40", "W41", "W42"), class = "factor"), point = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L), x = c(-7.064, -5.1681, 
-6.4866, -2.7522, -4.6305, -4.2957, -3.7552, -4.9482, -5.6452, 
-6.0302, -5.3244, -3.9819, -3.8123, -5.3085, -5.6096, -6.4557, 
-5.2549, -3.4893, -3.5909, -2.5546, -3.7247, -5.1733, -3.3451, 
-2.8993, -2.6835, -3.9495, -4.9649, -2.8438, -4.6926, -3.4768, 
-3.1221, -4.8175, -4.5641, -3.549, -3.08, -2.4153, -2.9882, -3.4045, 
-4.6394, -3.3404, -2.6728, -3.3517, -2.6098, -3.7733, -4.051, 
-2.9385, -4.5024, -4.59, -4.5617, -4.0658, -2.4986, -3.7559, 
-4.245, -4.8045, -4.6615, -4.0696, -4.6638, -4.6505, -3.7978, 
-4.5649, -5.7669, -4.519, -3.8561, -3.779, -3.0549, -3.1241, 
-2.1423, -3.2759, -4.224, -4.028, -3.3412, -2.8832, -3.3866, 
-0.1852, -3.3763, -4.317, -5.3607, -3.3398, -1.9087, -4.431, 
-3.7535, -3.2545, -0.806, -3.1419, -3.7269, -3.4853, -4.3129, 
-2.8891, -3.0572, -5.3309, -2.5837, -4.1128, -4.6631, -3.4695, 
-4.1045), y = c(7.76, 0.72, 4.1, 1.36, 0.13, -0.02, 0.13, 0.42, 
1.49, 2.64, 1.01, 0.08, 0.22, 1.01, 1.53, 4.39, 0.99, 0.56, 0.43, 
2.31, 0.31, 0.59, 0.62, 1.65, 2.12, 0.1, 0.24, 1.68, 0.09, 0.59, 
1.23, 0.4, 0.36, 0.49, 1.41, 3.29, 1.22, 0.56, 0.1, 0.67, 2.38, 
0.43, 1.56, 0.07, 0.08, 1.53, -0.01, 0.12, 0.1, 0.04, 3.42, 0.23, 
0, 0.34, 0.15, 0.03, 0.19, 0.17, 0.2, 0.09, 2.3, 0.07, 0.15, 
0.18, 1.07, 1.21, 3.4, 0.8, -0.04, 0.02, 0.74, 1.59, 0.71, 10.64, 
0.64, -0.01, 1.06, 0.81, 4.58, 0.01, 0.14, 0.59, 7.35, 0.63, 
0.17, 0.38, -0.08, 1.1, 0.89, 0.94, 1.52, 0.01, 0.1, 0.38, 0.02
)), .Names = c("group", "point", "x", "y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-95L))
```

Here's the plot my attempts to overlay a legend:

```
> attach(v1)    
> plot(x,y, pch=16, col=group)   #simple plot, automatic colors
> #first legend
> legend("topleft", legend=group, pch=16, col=group)
> # colors matched, but it's breaking out every point
> legend("topright", legend=levels(group), pch=16, col=group)
> # Corrected the number of levels in legend, but no colors
>
```

You can see that the first legend appears correct color-wise, but it shows an entry for every point and runs out of space.  The second legend shows group as factor levels, which is what I want, but it doesn't change the colors.

I realize that I could color as a vector (e.g. col(c("black","red", etc.), but since the original plot command automatically assigned colors, I'm looking to do it "automatically" in my legend and avoid the risk of putting the wrong colors in my vector.

Thanks!

Comment: Try : `legend("topleft", legend=levels(group), pch=16, col=unique(group))` also, i would strongly suggest `ggplot2` which would give the same with `ggplot(v1)+geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y,colour=group))+theme_bw()` but offers a lot of flexibility.

Comment: @Haboryme Thanks, that does the trick.  Since you sent that as a comment rather than answer, I'm not able to mark it as answered for you.

Comment: I had forgotten, took the time to post it this time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**base R solution:**

```
attach(v1)    
plot(x,y, pch=16, col=group)
legend("topleft", legend=levels(group), pch=16, col=unique(group))
```

**ggplot2 solution**

```
ggplot(v1)+
   geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y,colour=group))+
   theme_bw()
```

Again, I would strongly suggest the use of ggplot2 over base R unless you're only exploring the data. There are plenty of questions/answers on the matter on SO.

Answer (score 4):

Try creating a new column in `v1` that is a number based on the value of `group` (as a factor). Pass this column as the `col` when plotting the points. Then create a vector of numbers for `legend` in the same way and pass that as the `col` for `legend`.

```
v1$cols = as.numeric(as.factor(v1$group))
legend.cols = as.numeric(as.factor(levels(v1$group)))
plot(v1$x , v1$y, pch=16, col=v1$cols)
legend("topright", legend=levels(group), pch=16, col=legend.cols)
```